# Wordpress / codeigniter transfer sql database password

Tags: mysql, wordpress, passwords

I am on a problem which need a quick solution. I will try to explain it.

I have the table wp_user (from WordPress), where all the members have password encrypted with a wordpress encrypting function. And I have to transfer this table to a new Mysql Database on a new web site working with Codeigniter.

For new members on the new site which works under codeigniter, I use the MD5 function in order to mask password.

But the problem is that the two functions are different, so when an older user try to connect on my new web site, that doesn't work because the passwords don't match ...

So, how I can do for translate the wordpress encrpyting in a normal MD5 password?

Or maybe it's not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you'll have to perform both checks, or just change CI to use the same hashing scheme as WP. That's probably the easier option. If you really want to start using the default CI hashing scheme, you could store both hashes and update the new hash on successful login (when you have the plaintext password).

Comment: Ok thx, so i have to find the function in wordpress which encrypt password ...

Do u know where I can find it ?

Comment: If you're using the latest version of WP, it's `wp_hash_password` in `wp-includes/pluggable.php`. This will start you down the trail. The actual algorithm used depends on your settings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with what kind of hashing Wordpress uses for passwords, but I assume that it is secure and irreversible. The hashed passwords *cannot* be converted to their MD5 equivalent because hashing is a one-way algorithm.

Here is my suggestion for you:

Add a `using_md5_flag` boolean column to the users table in your new website with default value `0`. Copy the passwords over from Wordpress into a column `wppassword` and also create a column called `md5password` When users log into the system perform the following code (assumes Datamapper ORM, convert to Active Record if you need to):

```
$u = new User();
$u->where('username', $this->input->post('username'))->get();

$y = new User();
$y->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
if($u->using_md5_flag){
    /*the flag is 1*/
    $y->where('md5password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $y->get();
    if($y->exists()) echo "setting cookie and redirecting to logged in area";
    else echo "Wrong credentials!";
}

else{
    /*the flag is 0, use wordpress's hashing algorithm (not sure what this is)*/
    $y->where('wppassword', wp_hashing_algo($this->input->post('password')));
    $y->get();
    if($y->exists()){
        /*set the using_md5_flag flag so next time they log in it will ignore wp's*/
        $y->using_md5_flag = 1;
        /*set the new md5 password.*/
        $y->md5password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
        $y->save();
        echo "setting cookie and redirecting to logged in area";
    }
    else{
        echo "Wrong credentials.";
    }
}
```

This code hasn't been tested, I wrote it inside StackOverflow's editor... but It's the method I'd take to perform slow conversion to a more secure hash. Lastly, if you're looking for a really secure hash, check out Bcrypt ([phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)), it's more resistant to rainbow table attacks.

---

**Update 1:** If you need to use the Phpass library with CodeIgniter, you can find a copy I modified [here](http://pastebin.com/R5aVDve6) (I added a constructor). Put this in `libraries/Phpass.php` You can use the library in your controllers using:

```
$this->load->library("phpass", array("iteration_count_log2" => 8, "portable_hashes" => FALSE));
$check = $this->phpass->CheckPassword($this->input->post('password'), $u->password);
if($check) /*logged in*/
else /*wrong credentials.*/
```

When you download the Phpass file it comes with a `test.php` file which demos how the functions work. I suggest reviewing it.

Comment: So when I use the crypting class of WP nammed PasswordHash I have a problem, the scheme returned is never the same, so it's impossible to match the password if the scheme returned is not the same when I apply the algorithm ... someone has an idea ?

Comment: For a password example like 'test', the crypting sentence associated is never the same when I apply the function PasswordHash of WP.
So it's impossible to check if the password match or not with the scheme in the sql row of a member ... it's normal ?

Comment: Have you discovered what hashing algo your version of WP uses? I just briefly looked into this - From what I could find they used to use MD5 but upgraded to Phpass (Bcrypt). See my update above.